# Is there an option to create consumers that accept only messages with high priority in RabbitMQ and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm creating an application that sends messages for time-expensive processing to a consumer using RabbitMQ. However, I need to prioritize messages. When a message with high priority arrives, it must be processed even if all consumer instances are processing other messages.

AFAIK there is no possibility to preempt processing low-priority messages and switch to processing high-priority messages in Spring Boot and RabbitMQ.

Is it possible to create consumers that accept only high-priority messages or to run additional set of consumers on the fly when all other are busy and high-priority messages arrive?

I tried to add queues with x-max-priority=10 flag and to increase number of consumers but it doesn't solve my problem.

Imagine that we run 50 consumers and send 50 messages with low priority. While time-expensive processing is being performed, a new message arrives with high priority but it cannot be processed at once because all 50 consumers are busy.

There is a part of configuration that sets number of consumers

```java
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory
rabbitListenerContainerFactory(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                               @Qualifier("rabbitConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
  SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
  configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
  factory.setConcurrentConsumers(50);
  factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(100);
  return factory;
}
```

Is there a way to create a set of consumers that accept messages high-priority messages (e.g. higher than 0) or to create consumer on the fly for high-priority messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about a way to implement the preemptive strategy you describe, but there's a number of alternative things that you could consider.

### Priority Setting

The first thing to take into account is the `priority` support in RabbitMQ itself.

Consider this excerpt from RabbitMQ in Depth by Gavin M. Roy:

> “As of RabbitMQ 3.5.0, the priority field has been implemented as per the AMQP specification. It’s defined as an integer with possible values of 0 through 9 to be used for message prioritization in queues. As specified, if a message with a priority of 9 is published, and subsequently a message with a priority of 0 is published, a newly connected consumer would receive the message with the priority of 0 before the message with a priority of 9”.

e.g.

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("Hello World!", message -> {
  MessageProperties properties = MessagePropertiesBuilder.newInstance()
                                                         .setPriority(0)
                                                         .build();
  return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
                       .andProperties(properties)
                       .build();
});
```

### Priority-based Exchange

A second alternative is to define a topic exchange and define a routing key that considers your priority.

For example, consider an exchange of `events` using a routing key of pattern `EventName.Priority` e.g. `OrderPlaced.High`, `OrderPlaced.Normal` or `OrderPlaced.Low`.

Based on that you could have a queue bound to just orders of high priority i.e. `OrderPlaced.High` and a number of dedicated consumers just for that queue.

e.g.

```
String routingKey = String.format("%s.%s", event.name(), event.priority());
rabbit.convertAndSend(routingKey, event);
```

With a listener like the one below where the queue `high-priority-orders` is bound to the `events` exchange for event `OrderPlaced` and priority `High` using routing key `OrderPlaced.High`.

```
@Component
@RabbitListener(queues = "high-priority-orders", containerFactory="orders")
public class HighPriorityOrdersListener {

 @RabbitHandler
 public void onOrderPlaced(OrderPlacedEvent orderPlaced) {
   //...
 }
}
```

Obviously, you will need a dedicated thread pool (in the `orders` container factory above) to attend the high priority requests.

Comment: This quote by Gavin M. Roy conflicts with the official docs that say "Larger numbers indicate higher priority." https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html

Comment: @Politechniczny perhaps they will correct it in other revisions of the book.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism in the AMQP protocol to "select" messages from a queue.

You might want to consider using discrete queues with dedicated consumers instead.

BTW, this is not spring related; general questions about RabbitMQ should be directed to the rabbitmq-users Google group.